# ANDROID STUDIO- Service not working when device disconnected to power

Tags: java, service, alarmmanager

I have a problem and that is that the service I use in an Android project does not work when I disconnect the device from the power. If it is connected, it does work. I have tried many alternatives and the last thing I tried is this.

I need help... anything that can solve this problem?

Android Manifest and Service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.resolucion.probando" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Probando" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SegundaActivity"></activity>
        
        <service android:process=":remote"  android:name=".NuevoIntento"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
public class NuevoIntento extends Service {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor;
    private Context context;
    TextView tv;
  int hora;
int minutos;
int seconds;
int minutosumado;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       Log.e("TAG", "Service binding");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        setNotification();
        if (scheduleTaskExecutor == null) {
            scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        tv = layout.findViewById(R.id.hora);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public void setNotification() {
        PendingIntent contentIntent;
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("MainActivity")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                        .setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.black))
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setAutoCancel(false)
                        .setContentText("MyApp");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(101, mBuilder.build());

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
     startMyOwnForeground(); //NOTIFICATION_ID is a random integer value which has to be unique in an app
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground(){
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
        String channelName = "My Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    private class mainTask implements Runnable {
    
        public void run() {
   
        Log.e("TAG","TAG");
         }

        }
       }
```